# Display dynamic list on single pygame window

Tags: python, pygame, n-queens

I want to simulate n queens problem using backtracking.
I am calling this drawboard() function every time with a list as argument like below

```
def show_columns(x): 
    print "columns:", x
    if len(x)!=0:
        draw_board(x)
```

This list 'x' is returned from a recursive procedure and so will be updating after each iteration

So each time it is shown in separate windows.The next window is shown only after cloasing the first one and so on...

How can i make the things in a single window, or else how can i automatically close these windows after a particular time interval so that these windows are shown one by one

My function to draw chess board is as follows

```
def draw_board(the_board): 
    pygame.init()
    colors = [(255,178,102), (255,255,255)] 
    surface_sz = 480            
    sq_sz = surface_sz // n     
    surface_sz = n * sq_sz      


    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((surface_sz, surface_sz))
    ball = pygame.image.load("queen.png")    


    while True:

        ev = pygame.event.poll()
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break;


        for row in range(n):           
            c_indx = row % 2           
            for col in range(n):       
                the_square = (col*sq_sz, row*sq_sz, sq_sz, sq_sz)
                surface.fill(colors[c_indx], the_square)

                c_indx = (c_indx + 1) % 2


        for (col, row) in enumerate(the_board):
          surface.blit(ball,
                   (col*sq_sz+ball_offset,row*sq_sz+ball_offset))

        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change the archetecture of your program a bit to get it to work with a persistent UI. Rather than having your simulation code call the UI to update, make it work the other way around, with the UI requesting a new board state from the sim.

You haven't shown any of your sim code, so I'm not sure what its implementation is, but perhaps you could refactor it to be a generator, yielding values one by one?

Then you'd make your UI be:

```
def app():
    pygame.init()
    colors = [(255,178,102), (255,255,255)] 
    surface_sz = 480            
    sq_sz = surface_sz // n     
    surface_sz = n * sq_sz      

    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((surface_sz, surface_sz))
    ball = pygame.image.load("queen.png")    

    the_sim = sim_generator()        # start the simulation

    for the_board in the_sim:        # loop over the values yielded from the simulation
        ev = pygame.event.poll()
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break;

        for row in range(n):           
            c_indx = row % 2           
            for col in range(n):       
                the_square = (col*sq_sz, row*sq_sz, sq_sz, sq_sz)
                surface.fill(colors[c_indx], the_square)
                c_indx = (c_indx + 1) % 2

        for (col, row) in enumerate(the_board):
          surface.blit(ball,
                   (col*sq_sz+ball_offset,row*sq_sz+ball_offset))
        pygame.display.flip()            # you might want to add a frame delay
    pygame.quit()
```

This will quit as soon as the simulation yields its last value. If you want the final result to stay on the screen until you close it, you can add an extra loop that just checks for the window closing without redrawing anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097072/how-to-pass-python-list-dynamically-to-another-python-file

Comment: The resultant list from the file is given to the draw_board() function